# Using wildcard and non-wildcard TLS certificate with Kubernetes 1.3 Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

Everything in my Kubernetes configuration works great with a single TLS certificate. I define the cert as a `Secret` and reference it in my `Ingress` object configuration by name and my HTTPS traffic is served with the certificate.

My problem comes in when I try to use my other certificate as well. One of my certs has `www.DomainA.com` as the CN and `DomainA.com,DomainB.com,DomainC.com` as SAN's. The other one of my certs is a wildcard for `*.DomainA.com`.

When I add both certs to my Kubenetes configuration (with or without a defined [`hosts`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/extensions/v1beta1/definitions/#_v1beta1_ingresstls) field for either/both), only the first specified cert is added in the interface and served to any traffic.

What is odd is that when I run a `kubectl describe ingress my-ingress` I see:

```
TLS:
  non-wildcard-cert terminates DomainA.com,DomainB.com,DomainC.com
  wildcard-cert terminates *.DomainA.com
```

So I know both certs were picked up by Kubernetes, it just doesn't seem to be used (or stored) in GCP.

How can I use both of these certs?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, for now, GCP doesn't support the [Kubernetes spec](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/extensions/v1beta1/definitions/#_v1beta1_ingresstls) correctly according to the [GCE Ingress Controller doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ingress/controllers/gce/README.md#tls). When they do add the full SNI support from the spec, I should be able to do what I need.

I see that the [nginx Ingress controller has SNI support](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/multi-tls) but I only want to use the official, transparent, Google-maintained Ingress controller.